# Is tyrannicide (killing a tyrant) legal in America

Tags: united-states, law

Is tyrannicide (killing of a tyrant) legal in America? I was thinking about this after I heard it was legal in Julius Caesar era Rome. Also, how will we as a society decide when someone is a tyrant, or when the government is tyranical and we should remove them?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this the entire basis of the Second Amendment, i.e. if a tyrant were to take over the US, the people would be well-armed enough to overthrow them?

Comment: @F1Krazy the second amendment is rather vaguely worded, so whether it means that is a matter of controversy, and in any event "overthrow" does not mean "kill."

Comment: @F1Krazy exactly what I was thinking

Comment: Law.SE might be the better place for this.

Comment: what's that? a stackexchange?

Comment: Yes. https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @allure thx! I think its an intruiging question.

Comment: Since this is now on the Law.SE (https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77978/is-tyrannicide-killing-a-tyrant-legal-in-america) I'm voting to close this as not related to governments.

Comment: @allure I guess, I was hoping to discuss if from a political POV

Comment: @Allure I support the *Kovy Jacob*; the Q clearly shows the political relevance. Maybe it could be edited slightly by Kovy to show this political POV even more clearly, but it was plenty clear for me. Pls keep it open, it is a great Q, and desrves to be answered here. I hope someone with better understanding of the issue chimes in. I don't like my own answer that much, BTW, but incidentally, it is way **too** political. :)

Comment: @TimurShtatland :-)

Comment: What do you mean by tyrant? A tyrannical spouse, parent, boss? (That's usually deemed to be murder.) A duly elected or appointed US official who some people think is a tyrant? (That's usually deemed to be assassination.) A political figure in a foreign country with whom the US doesn't have a beef? (That's also highly frowned upon.)

Comment: @DavidHammen A tyrannical leader. President, really.

Comment: @Allure the [Law.SE] question has been closed and deleted.  Kovy Jacob: you might be able to get some useful answers over there if you ask slightly more specific questions.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Not at all. With the American Revolutionary War a recent memory, the Second Amendment was largely put in place so that states could have militias to protect them from foreign invasion (such as a retaliatory act from Great Britain, as in fact happened later on), as is stated quite clearly in the amendment itself.

Comment: Some people would argue that speed limits on public roads are tyranny. Other people would argue that assassinating people who speak out against the government is not tyranny. So depending on where you stand on the libertarian vs. authoritarian axis, your definition of "tyrant" can differ a lot and might not align with that of the legal system trying you for killing someone who would be a tyrant according to *your* definition. So first you would need to properly define what a "tyrant" is in the context of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US killing a private citizen is illegal except in self-defense or the defense of others (or if... well, let's not get political). Killing a public office-holder carries even higher punishments. A failed tyrant might be publicly executed for treason under federal law, but that's an extremely high bar to meet.  A successful tyrant will undermine US law, so this question becomes moot.

Killing a tyrant would only be 'legal' if the supposed tyrant were engaged in a violent crime or public insurrection, and the man doing the killing was directly involved (a victim of the crime, or part of some armed opposition to the insurrection). It's a weakness (and strength) of democracy everywhere that even the worst of us can make political statements and take political actions with relative impunity.

If we ever see a successful tyranny in the US (which we inch closer towards every day) then you will have to ask whether it is legal under *that* political system to kill a tyrant, because the US system will be defunct. But tyrants generally don't approve of tyrannicide (for purely selfish reasons) so that's unlikely to be legal either.

Comment: It wouldn't fall under the declaration of independance's allowance for the people to remove a tyranical gov't and replace it?

Comment: I think it should also be noted that the constitution defines constitutionality of something not legality of it.

Comment: @KovyJacob: The Declaration isn't law; it's a call to insurrection against the *then* (ostensible) tyrant George III.

Comment: @TedWrigley Ya but with recognizing the right of the people to remove a tyranical government, why wouldn't that extend to when the United States is a country? Its the basis of the American system.

Comment: @KovyJacob If anything, it’s a model that can be used to write a new manifesto for a new rebellion against the government.  But even in the Declaration, nowhere do they suggest King George is *not* the legitimate king of Britain or that he should be killed. He just should not be *their* king, because he was being tyrannical to *them*.

Comment: @KovyJacob: Because it's insurrection. Period, full stop. Insurrection cannot logically be legal, because insurrection obviates the rule of law. If someone wants to declare the US govt a tyranny and depose its duly elected leaders (installing leaders they prefer) that is by definition an insurrection. If they win, fine; they can say it's legal *after the fact*, once they have the power to write law. If they lose, they are criminals and traitors, nothing more.

Comment: "except in self-defense or the defense of others": or in accordance with a death warrant issued by the executive pursuant to a conviction and sentence of death imposed by a court.